# I have this for loop "for (int a = 1; a <= floor; a++)" twice in my code. The first one works fine, but the second one doesn't read the floor variable

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string location;
    const int minFloor = 1, maxFloor = 5, minRoom = 1, maxRoom = 30;
    int floor, room, singleRoom, doubleRoom, kingRoom, suiteRoom;
    int singleRate = 60, doubleRate = 75, kingRate = 100, suiteRate = 150;
    double income, occupancyRate, total_of_rooms, occupiedRoom, unoccupiedRoom;



    cout << "\nEnter the total number of floors in the hotel: ";
    cin >> floor; // not more than 5

    while (floor < minFloor || floor > maxFloor)
    {
        cout << "\nTne number of floors should be between 1 and 5 !! Please try again." << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter the total number of floors in the hotel: ";
        cin >> floor;
    }


    for (int a = 1; a <= floor; a++)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter total number of rooms in the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> room; //not more than 30

        while (room < minRoom || room > maxRoom)
        {
            cout << "\nThe number of rooms should be between 1 and 30 !! Please try again." << endl;
            cout << "\nEnter total number of room in the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> room;
        }

        cout << "\nHow many SINGLE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> singleRoom;

        cout << "How many DOUBLE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> doubleRoom;

        cout << "How many KING rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> kingRoom;

        cout << "How many SUITE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> suiteRoom;

        int totalRoom = singleRoom + doubleRoom + kingRoom + suiteRoom;
        
        while (totalRoom > room) //checking the sum
        {
            cout << "\nThe total number of occupied rooms exceeds the total number of rooms on this floor. Please try again !!";
            
            cout << "\nHow many SINGLE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> singleRoom;

            cout << "How many DOUBLE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> doubleRoom;

            cout << "How many KING rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> kingRoom;

            cout << "How many SUITE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> suiteRoom;

            int totalRoom = singleRoom + doubleRoom + kingRoom + suiteRoom;

            if (totalRoom < room)
                break; //break cause otherwise this thing won't stop
        }


    }


   for (int a = 1; a <= floor; a++) //for some reason it doesn't read the floor variable
    {
        income = (singleRoom * singleRate) + (doubleRoom * doubleRate) + (kingRoom * kingRate) + (suiteRoom * suiteRate);
        
        total_of_rooms = room;

        occupiedRoom = singleRoom + doubleRoom + kingRoom + suiteRoom;

    }
    
    cout << "Hotel Income: " << "$" << income << endl
    << "Total # of rooms: " << total_of_rooms << endl

    << "Total # of Occupied Rooms: " << occupiedRoom << endl

}
```

If you input 2 for the floor variable then the first time it does work, I get asked the number of rooms in both 1st and 2nd floor. But at the end when is time to make my calculations for the income it shows only the income as if it was only 1 and not 2. Also tried with different numbers in every way possible.

the input for floor should be 2.
Then 1st floor: 20 rooms. single 10, double 2, king 1 and suite 1.
2nd floor: 10 rooms. single 5, double 1, king and suite 0.
The final income should be 1375
Total of rooms 30
occupied rooms 20 and unoccupied 10

What I get is income: 375
total rooms: 10
occupied 6 and unoccupied 4

Comment: What is the input you are providing? You should remove the `**` in the code. Bold does not work in code blocks.

Comment: the input is anything in between 1 and 5. the ** were added here when I edited it sorry.

Comment: For each floor you read into the same variables. Whatever was entered for the last floor wins. Same for the income at the bottom. If you want to sum the values for each floor together you'll need to initialize them to 0, input into a temporary variable, then add it to the existing value.

Comment: When we ask for the specific input you are using it is because we are trying to replicate the same conditions you are seeing. Be specific. You should also say what the expected output is for that specific input.

Answer (score 1):

The `income` and `total_of_rooms` and `occupiedRoom` are being reset.

You want to accumulate them.

Try `+=` instead of `=` for those variables.

You need to do these calculations in the end of the first loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string location;
    const int minFloor = 1, maxFloor = 5, minRoom = 1, maxRoom = 30;
    int floor, room, singleRoom, doubleRoom, kingRoom, suiteRoom;
    int singleRate = 60, doubleRate = 75, kingRate = 100, suiteRate = 150;
    double income = 0, occupancyRate, total_of_rooms = 0, occupiedRoom = 0, unoccupiedRoom = 0;



    cout << "\nEnter the total number of floors in the hotel: ";
    cin >> floor; // not more than 5

    while (floor < minFloor || floor > maxFloor)
    {
        cout << "\nTne number of floors should be between 1 and 5 !! Please try again." << endl;
        cout << "\nEnter the total number of floors in the hotel: ";
        cin >> floor;
    }


    for (int a = 1; a <= floor; a++)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter total number of rooms in the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> room; //not more than 30

        while (room < minRoom || room > maxRoom)
        {
            cout << "\nThe number of rooms should be between 1 and 30 !! Please try again." << endl;
            cout << "\nEnter total number of room in the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> room;
        }

        cout << "\nHow many SINGLE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> singleRoom;

        cout << "How many DOUBLE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> doubleRoom;

        cout << "How many KING rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> kingRoom;

        cout << "How many SUITE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
        cin >> suiteRoom;

        int totalRoom = singleRoom + doubleRoom + kingRoom + suiteRoom;
        
        while (totalRoom > room) //checking the sum
        {
            cout << "\nThe total number of occupied rooms exceeds the total number of rooms on this floor. Please try again !!";
            
            cout << "\nHow many SINGLE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> singleRoom;

            cout << "How many DOUBLE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> doubleRoom;

            cout << "How many KING rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> kingRoom;

            cout << "How many SUITE rooms are occupied on the " << a << "th Floor: ";
            cin >> suiteRoom;

            totalRoom = singleRoom + doubleRoom + kingRoom + suiteRoom; // removed the local variable

            
        }



        income += (singleRoom * singleRate) + (doubleRoom * doubleRate) + (kingRoom * kingRate) + (suiteRoom * suiteRate);
        
        total_of_rooms += room;

        occupiedRoom += singleRoom + doubleRoom + kingRoom + suiteRoom;

    }
    
    cout << "Hotel Income: " << "$" << income << endl
    << "Total # of rooms: " << total_of_rooms << endl

    << "Total # of Occupied Rooms: " << occupiedRoom << endl

}
```

Comment: Alright so I tried that after reading your answer which by the way thank you. But then it wouldn't let me run the program until I initialized the variables (which I did to 0) and the results were Income: 750, total rooms: 20, occupied: 12 and unoccupied: 8